# How to set the x-axis to start at the bottom of the chart in highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When I have a chart and all the data are zero,the x-axis is centered. (jsfiddle)

[image]

but What I need is to start at bottom of the chart, like this:

[image]

How can I do this with HighChart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set yAxis `max` and `min`.

```
yAxis: {
    max: 0.06,
    min: 0
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/hFFwL/)

For dinamically modified.

```
function preventZeroLabel() {
    var axis = this.yAxis[0];
    if( -axis.min == axis.max ) {
        axis.setExtremes(0, 1, true);
    }
}

chart: {
    events: {
        load: preventZeroLabel,
        redraw: preventZeroLabel
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/hFFwL/4/)

Comment: The issue with this is that if the data is more than the max it will not show up. example: http://jsfiddle.net/LCYSY/

Comment: @Jimmy Of course you have to update it if you change chart data, take a look my update.